# Do I have to declare in my resume about my 2-month employment in a government office where I have a bad experience with other employees?

Tags: resume, job-change, resignation, job-description

After a long period of unemployment due to reviewing for some major licensure exams, I landed a job at a government office.

However, I discovered I had been hacked by some other employees. They kept mentioning contents of my laptop, social media accounts, cellphones and even had someone spy over me whenever I get out of the office. My boss knew what they are doing because I already informed him about it after discovering what they did after more than a week of being employed.

However, my boss could not do anything about it. So I resigned, citing the hacking in my resignation letter. The hacking appeared to continue after I had resigned.

Now that I am looking for new jobs, I would like to demonstrate the skills and experience I gained from my last one. However, owing to the bad experience I had with the people there, I am opting to put them out of my resume.

How can I show my competence and skills for the job without needing to mention that employment?

Comment: If you are EU or Australia, this would most certainly be a huge breach of privacy. Pretty sure the same is true in many other jurisdictions. You should try throwing whatever privacy principles your location has at your (ex)supervisor...

Comment: I've revised your question so it is easier to read/follow - please edit it further if I've missed some important point.

Comment: Re-reading the question (before editing it) - I don't think you should be bothering with your ex-supervisor. If you have evidence of any breach in privacy, you need to talk to the police and a lawyer. For one - these guys have accessed your laptop and may have gotten personal identification details, and even bank details.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate, actually...

Comment: Ahem, they are breaking the law and your boss could not do something about it? wow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I omit previous work experience from future job applications and my resume?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/21541/can-i-omit-previous-work-experience-from-future-job-applications-and-my-resume)

Answer (score 6):

No, you don't have to include that job on your resume. But, then, you can't use it as evidence of any skills.

That said - no employer is going to look at any skills acquired or exercised in such a short previous employment. 2 months is barely enough time for most people to get beyond figuring out the coffee machine, never mind exercise real job-related skills.

Just leave it off the resume and look for your next job.

Comment: Exactly what I would have said, in addition - at most places there is usually a probationary period and during this period either party can terminate the contract without cause. At my work, this is 90 days; some places it is 60 days. So you really don't even need to bother with it. You may open yourself up to all sorts of questions as to [a] what kind of experience could you have possibly gained in such a short time and [b] why did you quit.